# How to freeze/stop JavaScript execution until a function is done

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, electron

**I want to know how can I freeze/stop JavaScript execution until a function is finished (Using JavaScript/NodeJS).**
For example:
[image]

The first line of code in the console shows an alert to the use, JavaScript execution is frozen/stopped until the user clicks `ok`.
[image]

And when that is done the second line of code will continue to execute
[image]

Now, I know that I should use *async* functions to do that, but that isn't working, here's my node code that is loaded in a preload script of a `webview` in *Electron*:

```
global.alert = async (text) => {
  //replace it with custom alert!
  ipcRenderer.sendToHost('ShowAnAlert', {
    theWebsiteLink: location.href,
    theMessage: text
  });
  var a = await function(){
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      ipcRenderer.on('GetResult', () => {
        console.log("Done!");
        resolve("result");
      });
    });
  }();
  return a;
}
```

But it doesn't freeze/stop JavaScript execution when it's preformed. **How can I fix that?**

**EDIT 1:**
Ok, turns out that *asynchronous* isn't the answer that I'm looking for.

```
global.alert = (text) => {
  //replace it with custom alert!
  ipcRenderer.sendToHost('ShowAnAlert', {
    theWebsiteLink: location.href,
    theMessage: text
  });
  var a = ipcRenderer.on('GetResult', () => {
    console.log("Done!");
  });
  return a;//this is returned as undefined
}
```

I've removed *asynchronous* parts in the script. But the function isn't freezing/stopping JavaScript execution. Any idea how can I do this?

**EDIT 2:**
If this isn't possible to do in pure JavaScript, is there some other ways to do this using *Electron native functions* or *Electron Libraries/modules*

Answer (score 2):

An async function, by definition, is asynchronous and does not stop the execution of the script. If you wanted it to stop the execution, you'd need to remove the asynchronous parts of it (the Promise, async & await).

The part

```
var a = ipcRenderer.on('GetResult', () => {
    console.log("Done!");
  });
```

is an event listener so it will wait for the "GetResult" event before running the console.log within it. This will also return undefined, hence why `a` is undefined.

Comment: I've tried to remove the asynchronous parts, but it's not freezing/stopping JavaScript form execution.